# cannot convert ‘double’ to ‘double*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘float sumall(double arr[])

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I am a C & Assembly programmer. But C++ is so dumb. I cannot understand what I am doing wrong here. Can someone explain to me why I am getting this error? Here is my code:
  GNU nano 2.2.6                  Файл: assignment4.cpp

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

#define SIZE 10
int counter = 0;
const double TAX = 1.13;

float sumall(double arr[]);

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{       double array[SIZE] = {0,0,0
                             ,0,0,0  
                             ,0,0,0  
                             ,0};

    while (counter < (SIZE-1))
    {
            if (array[counter-1] == -99)
                    break;
            else continue;
            std::cout << "Enter any number [1 WORD long]: ";
            std::cin >> array[counter];
            ++counter;
    }

    std::cout << "The total price is: $" << sumall(array[SIZE]);
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

float sumall(double arr[])
    {
            float total=0;
                    for(int i=0;i<SIZE;++i)
                    {
                            total+=arr[i];
                    }
            total*=TAX;
    return (total*TAX);
}
```

Also, how can I fix this error using templates (which I heard is possible in C++), thanks!

Comment: So, C++ is dumb, because you don't understand it?  Is your preferred language, C, also dumb?  Because apparently you don't understand that either, since, if you took out the C++ specific code, you would get the same error, for the same reason in C.

Comment: So he claimed to be a C programmer. LOL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have `int counter = 0;`  and `if (array[counter-1] == -99)`
in the very first iteration of the loop, you will access index `0 - 1 = -1`.

in your `sumall` function, you declared it to return float, but since you are summing doubles the final value will be double

and you better use `const int SIZE = 0`, much more safer than using `#define`

and in your function call to `sumall`, `sumall(array[SIZE])`, no need to pass the array size.
just call it like this, `sumall(array)`

Comment: Don't mind that, I forgot to comment that out, my problem is why is it telling me that I am casting a pointer to non pointer? Where did I even initiate the pointer? Does C++ consider the list arr[] as a pointer? If so, how can I fix this using templates in C++, if possible? Or how can I fix the problem in general?

Comment: @user2993954, You mean non-pointer to pointer (clear from the error), and it's not casting, it's an implicit conversion, just like C.

Comment: yea, non-pointer to pointer sorry ... I tend to read things from end to start >> AT&T assembly kinda messed things up for me there ;)
And without worrying about the problem as Tahawi stated because I can simply reverse the program and change the carry flag in that operation from a zero-memory flag to a carry flag to negate the start of that process...

How can I actually fix my code, or where is it messing up?

Comment: @user2993954, try to change the way you are calling the function, check the edit in the answer

Answer (score 3):

I think it should be like this :

```
std::cout << "The total price is: $" << sumall(array);
```

Also total should be double

```
double sumall(double arr[])
    {
            double total=0;
                    for(int i=0;i<SIZE;++i)
                    {
                            total+=arr[i];
                    }
            total*=TAX;
    return (total*TAX);
}
```